# How to reclaim database space on Azure SQL Server after setting nvarchar values to null

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, disk-space

There is db space challenge at hand on **Azure** SQL Server database. 490 GB out of 500 GB is used. That's what I read from nice pie chart on Azure portal.
Notice that some of the techniques used on-prem won't work for Azure SQL Server Database.

Biggest table is `DidbStudySerumLevelDeviation`.

`exec sp_spaceused 'RulesEngine.DidbStudySerumLevelDeviation '`

returns

`+------------+------------------------------+
| name       | DidbStudySerumLevelDeviation |
| rows       | 20 805 409                   |
| reserved   | 133 332 840 KB               |
| data       | 123 079 792 KB               |
| index_size | 9 772 192 KB                 |
| unused     | 480 856 KB                   |
+------------+------------------------------+`

Table definition: 

`CREATE TABLE [RulesEngine].[DidbStudySerumLevelDeviation](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [PatientTherapyId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    ...
    [Abstract] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    ...
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RulesEngine.DidbStudySerumLevelDeviation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC,
    [PatientTherapyId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)`

Clustered index exists on primary key. There are also some nonclustered indexes.
Abstract column data takes around 90% of space of a table.

Procedure is run to set unnecessary `Abstract` column data to null. That should reduce problematic column "weight" to 10%. However this doesn't reduce database size. **How to reclaim that database space?**

Maybe I should wait and some Azure SLQ maintenance magic occurs? It sounds like wishfull thinking though.

*Regarding possible duplicate*

Answer to this question might me specific to **Azure** deployment of SQL Server. Drop in database size reported in Azure portal or read from `exec sp_spaceused` didn't change.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik Are you suggesting to run `DBCC CLEANTABLE`. I don't think you do, but I don't understand last sentance in linked answer.

Comment: No, I'm suggesting you don't need it. That only works when you DROP a column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please defrag all indexes. As mentioned on [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dilkushp/2013/07/27/fragmentation-in-sql-azure/) article, fragmentation can claim a lot space.

Run sp_helpfile to verify the log is not consuming space also. If the log is big run the following statement to recover space.

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (log, 0)
```

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829322/reduce-azure-sql-database-size/45830080#45830080) thread I provided some queries that may be useful about database size.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm rebuilding indexes and checking index stats as you suggested. Thx. I'll report back when it's done.

Comment: Articles have helped. Thx. Some unused indexes were removed. That's fastest db space gain. Clustered index is rebuilt. That took some (down)time. One tiny thing. On Azure SQL database (as a service) log file size is not counted against database quota. To proove it, run`exec sp_helpfile` and compare sizes against database spice on overview tab in Azure portal.

Comment: Users have reported not able to scale down when log is big.